# How to design a ViewModel for a todo list application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel

I am creating a simple todo application which has two entities, `tasks` and `categories`.

To create a `task`, choosing a `category` is a must. For this, I figured I would need a ViewModel.

Here is the Task entity

```
public class Task
{
    public int taskId { get; set; }
    public int categoryId { get; set; }
    public string taskName { get; set; }
    public bool isCompleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime creationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime completionDate { get; set; }
    public string remarks { get; set; }
    public string completionRemarks { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Category entity

```
public class Category
{
    public int categoryId { get; set; }
    public string categoryName { get; set; }
}
```

How can I design a `TaskCategoryViewModel` so that I can bind the `category` in the `CreateTask` view?

**Edit:** I am using classic ADO.NET instead of Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

In the TaskViewModel (I would prefer naming it CreateTaskViewModel) create property for categories select list

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoriesSelectList;
```

In controller, bind that property before returning view (note that this also should be done in post handler, when ModelState is invalid)

```
public ViewResult Create()
{
     CreateTaskViewModel  model = new CreateTaskViewModel();
     model.CategoriesSelectList = _repository.AllCategories().Select(x=> new SelectListItem(){ Text = x.CategoryName, Value = x.CategoryId.ToString();}
}
```

And finally, in the view

```
Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, Model.CategoriesSelectList)
```

**Edit:**

In your code, `_repository.AllCategories()` should be replaced by your data access code, that returns object having type `IEnumerable<Category>`. It actually does not matter which data access technology you use. And do not forget to add the `using System.Linq;` statement to your controller file, if it's missing.

Comment: archil, when I type `_repository.GetAllCategories().`, I am not able to type `Select` without it throwing an error. I am using plain ADO.NET instead of EF or Linq to SQL. Might this be the reason? If possible, can you please modify your answer accordingly?

Comment: @KishorNanda _repository.GetAllCategories() is just sample code. In general, there should be object with type IEnumerable<Category>. It actually does not matter you use ADO.NET of EF

Answer (score 1):

Kishor,

the best bet is have model that hods definition for your task and for category (all in one)

here is how everything hangs together.

where

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories
```

is used for creating drop down list which is ready to use

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.NewTask.categoryId, Model.Categories) %>
```

this will create you nice dropdown list

```
    private IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories
    {
        get
        {
            List<Category> categories = new List<Category>
                                            {
                                                new Category() {categoryId = 1, categoryName = "test1"},
                                                new Category() {categoryId = 2, categoryName = "category2"}
                                            };
            return categories;
        }
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult CreateTask()
    {
        TaskModel taskModel = new TaskModel();
        LoadCategoriesForModel(taskModel);
        return View(taskModel);
    }

    private void LoadCategoriesForModel(TaskModel taskModel)
    {
        taskModel.Categories =
            GetCategories.Select(
                x =>
                new SelectListItem()
                    {Text = x.categoryName, Value = x.categoryId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)});
    }

    public ActionResult CreateTask(TaskModel taskModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // do your logic for saving
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            LoadCategoriesForModel(taskModel);
            return View(taskModel);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// your model for creation
    /// </summary>
    public class TaskModel
    {
        public Task NewTask { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Task
    /// </summary>
    public class Task
    {
        public int taskId { get; set; }
        public int categoryId { get; set; }
        public string taskName { get; set; }
        public bool isCompleted { get; set; }
        public DateTime creationDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime completionDate { get; set; }
        public string remarks { get; set; }
        public string completionRemarks { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Category
    /// </summary>
    public class Category
    {
        public int categoryId { get; set; }
        public string categoryName { get; set; }
    }
```